# Expose spring batch workflow steps/tasks in advance from an api

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

For a spring batch workflow using java dsl, for example:

```
@Bean
public Job myWorkFlow() {
    return jobBuilders.get("myWorkFlow")
           .start(myFlowA.doStepA())
           .next(myFlowB.doStepB())
           .next(myFlowC.doStepC())
           .end()
           .build();
```

Does spring batch expose any api to see the workflow sequence of steps/tasklets, before the job is triggered. Once the job is launched, I can see the details in the BATCH_ tables and can also use jobExplorer.

I can wire in Jobs:

```
@Autowired
    private List<? extends Job> jobs;
```

The job can be instanceof FlowJob, from which I can get stepNames. However, the step names are not ordered. (I think it gets from underlying map)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Does spring batch expose any api to see the workflow sequence of steps/tasklets, before the job is triggered.

No, there is no such API provided by Spring Batch.